# Is 1.6 seconds a typical time to fetch nearly 3.7 million rows from a table?

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I am trying to work out if we need to upgrade our server hardware or need to configure the MySQL settings to make things faster.

A simple `SELECT * From table` took 1.6 seconds from the command line. However `mysql-slow.log` shows that it takes 7 seconds when one of our processes from another server executes it. This seems very slow to me. The table contains three INT columns only.

It's an Ubuntu Rackspace cloud server. We have 4GB RAM and only 1.2GB is used up.

So do the numbers look about right or is there something wrong?

**Additional information**

I have added the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * From table here`:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you rif you run the MySQL client on these other machines? I'm thinking network latency here!

Comment: @ Vérace I am logging into MySQL from a remote machine and running the queries. So network latency could be an issue with the numbers that I see. However should the mysql-slow.log show those times because of network latency? Does it not give the times for the queries running locally?

Comment: What happens if you have a `PRIMARY KEY` on the table? Re. the log - does the query appear no matter where you perform it or what? It is my understanding that what appears in the slow query log has nothing to do with the network latency - it all happens on the server!

Answer (score 1):

Both 1.6s and 7s seem reasonable.  Some issues that lead to variations:

- Caching (Was I/O needed, or was everything sitting in RAM -- a factor of 10 variation is possible)
- Distance to other server (Ping time)
- Bandwidth to other server (Mb/sec)
- Client's ability to absorb that much data that fast
- Whether client is receiving it in chunks or all at once

But my question to you is -- what can you do with 3.7M rows all at once?  That is, this does not seem like a reasonable benchmark or whatever.

Back to the "caching".  Try this:

1. restart mysqld
2. run your test
3. run your test again -- likely to run faster.

Main cache:  for a 4GB server and InnoDB tables, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be something like 2G.

Answer (score 0):

The query is done only after the results have been delivered, so latency will be included, imho.
Could you post in your original questions  EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * ....?